# Label Does Not Change After TextBox OnTextChanged Event ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, textbox, label

I have a username TextBox and a Label which should update to (V or X) when the TextBox text is changed. The label is updated only if, for example I press a button which automatically refreshes the page.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" OnTextChanged="checkUsername" Width="80%"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="usernameCheck" runat="server" CssClass="checkL"></asp:Label>
```

And the aspx.cs

```
protected void checkUsername(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (username.Text.Length < 3 || username.Text.Length > 15)
    {
        //---Label = X (in red)
        usernameCheck.Text = "\u2715";
    }
    else
    {
        if (myBl.checkUsername(Convert.ToString(username)))
        {
            //---Label = X (in red)
            usernameCheck.Text = "\u2715";
        }
        else
        {
            //---Label = V (in green)
            usernameCheck.Text = "\u2713";
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `AutoPostBack="true"` to your TextBox. This will cause it to post back and for that server side event to fire.

There are much better ways of doing what you are trying to accomplish though, most of which do not require a full page postback. I would try to make an AJAX call using the javascript change event, and using something like a callback method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I do the same with a TextMode="password", I think the AutoPostBack="true" clears the password TextBox

Comment: When using textmode="password" the textbox will not persist after postback. This is a built in security measure. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your password box?

Comment: First to validate the password and Second to compare between password and re-password

Comment: I would do that on the client side. Avoids a postback and provides a better user experience. As for validating the password how are you needing to validate it?

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses. Basically I need to check the password length and maybe I will add some forbidden character and the 
re-password check.

Comment: This can all be done using javascript on the client side (making sure to still verify on the server side after submitting)

Comment: I actually have to use c#

Comment: You can use whatever language you want for your server side code

Comment: So how should I do that, how to update the label with the OnTextChanged event while TextMode="password"

Comment: [Attach an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the "change" event in Javascript and compare the values of the two password boxes, validate with a regex, etc.

Comment: I think I did not explain myself correctly, I am asking the same question as the main one but now the text box is set to TextMode="password", so if I set AutoPostBack="true", when I loss focus from the password TextBox the input disappears.

Comment: This is actually a security feature with password textboxes. With `AutoPostBack="true"` the password is being posted back to the server, however, the value is not persisted in the text box after the page is posted back, nor can it be set from the server side by setting the `Value` server side attribute. You can, however, get around this by setting the client side `value` HTML attribute: `password.Attributes.Add("value", "yourpassword");`. Keep in mind though that you are bypassing a security feature that is designed to prevent the user's password from being rendered in the page source.